# Difference between deep copy shallow copy and list comprehension

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

I am working on minCostpath problem using dynamic programming

```
import copy
a = [
  [1,3,1],
  [1,5,1],
  [4,2,1],
]

# dp = [[0 for x in range(len(a[0]))] for x in range(len(a))] #Method 1
dp = copy.copy(a) #Method 2

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i])

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(dp[i])

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
#         dp[i][j] += a[i][j] #Uncomment this if using method 1 
        if (i > 0 and j > 0):
            dp[i][j] += min(dp[i-1][j],dp[i][j-1])
        elif i > 0:
            dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][j]
        elif j > 0:
            dp[i][j] += dp[i][j - 1]
#     print(a[i])
#     print(dp[i])
print('After finding minCost')
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i])

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(dp[i])
```

I am getting correct answer when I used both method but grid array gets changed when using deep copy method.
Can anyone tell me why is that so?

Comment: Also If i use dp = [[0]*len(grid)]*len(grid[0])  I get rubbish answer

Comment: Why not to use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) and not reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

As you already imported copy library you could use deepcopy() method.

```
dp = copy.deepcopy(a) #Method 2
```

It worked for me!